# DAC code - It seems that the flow is to read the data from the reveal channel and write it to storage?

Tags: smart-rollup, rollup, scoru

Digging into the DAC code. It seems that the flow is to read the data from the reveal channel and write it to storage. So then to use that data i must read it again. Why read it, write it, and read it again instead of just reading it?

That's the current default flow, but nothing stops from doing something else with it.
`reveal_loop` takes a function to handle each content page.

What is the reasoning behind the default flow?
Question from Slack.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The main thing you want to watch out for, is if you get a very large DAC message, and your 'per page' function is expensive, you may easily end up in the situation of blowing past the tick limit.

The installer_kernel does this flow, however the tx-kernel currently reads the entire DAC page into a `vec!` in memory, before processing.This does result in going over the tick limit though, so there's work in progress to fix this.

Ah nicer potential approach could be to have the DAC reveal as more of a state machine: I reveal a certain amount, and then I may or may not process so far, reveal more, or exit the kernel and resume on the next runBut would be slightly trickier to implement - definitely possible though.

In the source there's a comment somewhere that says at 4 levels of depth, you can reveal a little under 8GB. How do you calculate this number?
**-->** **1 hash page -> 123 hashes.**

So 4 levels is `root_hash -> hash page -> hash page -> hash page -> content page` So `123 ^ 3 * 4091 / 1024 ^ 3 = 7.08` - so a bit over 7GB (or a bit under 8GB) in total of content.

3 levels then gives you 60 MB or so. (which revealing all in one go & writing to storage will be pretty close to the limit - need to validate that). It may be nicer to potentially have a 'maximum reveal size' rather than 'max levels' - would be more fine-grained at any rate.